# Returning only the entities where all sub-entities satisfy a certain condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two related tables, Branches and BranchStatus. What I want is to find all main branches (indicated by Branches.BranchSubCode = 0) where the status field in BranchStatus is 'MA' and where ALL sub branches (indicated by BranchSubCode > 0) have their status field be 'NN'. In the sample data I've provided in the fiddle linked below, this should mean that I only get two branches returned.

So far, I've managed to find a way to return all branches where the main branch status is 'MA' and where at least ONE sub branch has the status 'NN'. I also have a problem with my results being duplicated.

This is the code I've tried:

```
SELECT br.BranchCode
FROM Branches br JOIN
(SELECT br.ID 
      FROM branches br JOIN BranchStatus bs on br.ID = bs.BranchID
      WHERE bs.Status = 'MA') as mabranch
      ON mabranch.ID = br.ID
JOIN (SELECT BranchCode 
      FROM branches br JOIN BranchStatus bs on br.ID = bs.BranchID
      WHERE bs.Status = 'NN'
      AND br.BranchSubCode <> 0) as nnbranch
ON nnbranch.BranchCode = br.BranchCode
WHERE br.BranchSubCode = 0
```

In the sample data I've provided I'd be looking to only get the following BranchCodes returned: 1, 2

Instead my code currently returns 1, 1, 2, 5, 8

Please see this fiddle for sample data etc: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/90df4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most straightforward solution. Just following your requirements

```
select 
    a.BranchCode
from 
    Branches a
    join Branches b on a.BranchCode = b.BranchCode
    join BranchStatus c on a.ID = c.BranchID
    join BranchStatus d on b.ID = d.BranchID
where
    a.BranchSubCode = 0
    and b.BranchSubCode > 0
    and c.Status = 'MA'
group by a.BranchCode
having min(d.Status) = max(d.Status)  and min(d.Status) = 'NN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by running the query below for gain all main branches where the status field is 'MA' and where all his sub branches have their status field equals to 'NN':

```
SELECT
  b1.ID,
  b1.BranchCode
FROM Branches AS b1
    INNER JOIN BranchStatus AS bs1
        ON b1.ID = bs1.ID
WHERE b1.BranchSubCode = 0
    AND bs1.[Status] = 'MA'
    AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM Branches AS b2
                        INNER JOIN BranchStatus bs2
                            ON b2.ID = bs2.ID
                    WHERE bs2.[Status] = 'NN'
                        AND b2.ID = b1.ID
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Might be more efficient than the accepted solution but I like the accepted solution.

```
SELECT bm.ID, bm.BranchCode, bm.BranchSubCode, bmS.Status
     , bs.ID               , bs.BranchSubCode, bsS.Status
  FROM Branches bm
  JOIN Branches bs 
    on bs.BranchCode = bm.BranchCode  
   and bm.BranchSubCode = 0 
   and bs.BranchSubCode > 0 
  join BranchStatus bmS 
    on bmS.BranchID = bm.ID 
   and bmS.Status = 'MA' 
  join BranchStatus bsS 
    on bsS.BranchID = bs.ID 
   and bsS.Status = 'NN' 
  where not exists ( select 1 
                      from Branches bNot 
                      join BranchStatus bsSnot 
                        on bsSnot.ID = bNot.ID                         
                       and bNot.BranchCode = bm.BranchCode 
                       and bNot.BranchSubCode > 0
                       and bsSnot.Status <> 'NN'
                   )
```

Change to `select distinct bm.ID`